# Django redirect back to view from inside view decorator

Tags: python, django, redirect, python-decorators

I've been struggling to get Django's URL redirection to work inside of a decorator. Consider this simple decorator that ensures a view's `id` parameter is odd:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.utils.decorators import available_attrs

from functools import wraps

def ensure_odd_id(view):
    @wraps(view, assigned=available_attrs(view))
    def inner(request, *args, **kwargs):
        id = int(kwargs.get('id'))

        if id % 2 == 0:
            d = kwargs.copy()
            d['id'] = str(id + 1)

            return redirect(reverse(view, args=args, kwargs=d))

        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return inner

@ensure_odd_id
def test(request, id):
    return HttpResponse('test {}'.format(id))

urlpatterns = [url(r'^test/(?P<id>\d+)/$', test)]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    settings.configure(DEBUG=True, ROOT_URLCONF='test')

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    execute_from_command_line()
```

If you save this script as `test.py` and run it with `python test.py runserver`, you will see that requesting `/test/13` produces no error, but requesting `/test/18` produces a `NoReverseMatch` error for the call to `reverse`, instead of redirecting to `/test/19`:

```
NoReverseMatch at /test/18/
Reverse for 'test.test' with arguments '()'
    and keyword arguments '{'id': '19'}' not found.
    0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

I have a feeling this has to do with the fact that the `view` function is the un-decorated `view`, while the URL resolver only deals with the decorated view.

Is there any nice way to redirect to the decorated `view` itself without hacky introspection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django actually uses the view function itself in `reverse`, so I just need to pass in the decorated function instead of the original view:

```
return redirect(reverse(inner, args=args, kwargs=d))
                        ^^^^^
```